# Why did Modesty throw away her leaflets?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

Modesty is given some leaflets to hand out, but instead throws them high into the air. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modesty knows that her leaflets get briefly read then dumped by people who take them and that Chastity will use this as a measure of whether they've actually been handed out locally or just thrown into a waste bin in one go.

By throwing them into the air, she's simulating this process, thus giving her time to do whatever she wants rather than handing out leaflets.

> **CHASTITY:** (calling after them) *Hand out your leaflets! **I’ll know if you dump ’em.** Tell me if you see anything suspicious.*
>
> CLOSE ON CREDENCE – he’s washing dishes, but watching the children intently.
>
> MODESTY follows the last of the children out of the church.
>
> EXT. STREET OUTSIDE SECOND SALEM CHURCH—DAY
>
> MODESTY stands in the middle of the busy street. She throws her leaflets high into the air, watching with glee as they fall around her.

Comment: And of course, it's to make the audience think she's The Child Graves Is Looking For